# Multiple tabs of same view not updating through AJAX call in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC view which monitors contacts signing in to a system. Upon initialisation the view performs an AJAX call to update the view. This call is then repeated indefinitely with a 5 second delay. The Ajax call is to a method in my controller.

On initialisation the view contains a list of contact information for different people. Every 5 seconds the when view calls the update function within my controller, and the order of the objects will update based on who has signed in (the most recent sign ins are prepended to the list).

This has worked fine for a with just one tab, however I have just today tested with 4 machines logged on to this same view, and they are now freezing and not updating.

So my javascript showUpdates function is as follows:

```
 function showUpdates(){

        var vals = [];
        $('input:checkbox[name=locationCheckBoxes]:checked').each(function () {
            vals.push($(this).val());
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Attendee/SigninUpdates",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ checkBoxValues: vals }),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (result) {

                // This is the main AJAX that retrieves the cards detected.

                $.each(result, function (i, country) {
                    // Fade the section out
                    //if ($('#' + country.Id).css('opacity') != 1) {
                    $('#' + country.Id).fadeOut(100, function () {
                        // Animation complete.
                        $('#attendeeList').prepend($('#' + country.Id));
                        $('#' + country.Id).css('opacity', 0.9);

                    });
                    // Fade the section back in
                    $('#' + country.Id).fadeIn(100, function () {
                    });
                    //}
                });

                // After it is done call iteself again
                setTimeout(showUpdates, 4500);
            }
        });
    }
```

As you can see the interval between this function being called is 4.5 seconds. There are also checkboxes to allow the user to filter their different locations, so the multiple tabs could also be in different states in that regard too (i.e. 4 tabs all monitoring a different locations signins).

**EDIT**

My controller method is:

```
public JsonResult CardUpdates(int[] checkBoxValues)
    {

        List<int> LocIds = checkBoxValues.ToList();
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var user = DbContext.Users.Find(new object[] { userId });
        var org = DbContext.Organisations.Find(new object[] { user.OrganisationId });

        // Get the locations for that organisation
        var locations = DbContext.Locations.Where(x => x.Organisation.Id == org.Id).ToList();

        if (LocIds.Count() == 0)
        {
            foreach (var location in locations)
                LocIds.Add(location.Id);
        }

        var window = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-10);

        var result = inboundContext.Signins
            .Where(d => LocIds.Contains(d.LocationId) && d.DateOfContact >= window)
            .GroupBy(d => d.Id)
            .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateOfContact))
            .Select(d => d.Take(1)).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();

        result = result.Where(x => DbContext.Contacts.Where(y => y.Organisation.Id == org.Id)
                                            .Select(y => y.Id)
                                            .Contains(x.Id) && LocIds.Contains(x.LocationId)).OrderBy(x => x.DateOfContact).ToList();

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I'm posting on here because I'm not aware of the implications of having multiple tabs open on this view and how it might affect performance. Say they all log in and access the page simultaneously, what problems could it cause?

Like I say this runs absolutely fine on one tab and has been used extensively, what is the issue that multiple tabs has presented and how can I get around it?

Thanks

Comment: can you show controller?

Comment: @teovankot added now.

Comment: Is this running locally in development, i.e. Visual Studio?

Comment: @ChrisPratt No, the website is published via Azure. Decreasing the frequency of the ajax call seems to have helped, but I'm confused as to why, I'm not aware of any implications of having multiple instances of the website view the page with different locations selected. It's strange.

Comment: The only thing that would logically affect this, if if the server cannot respond to the load of your long-polling (which is why I thought you might be running in IIS Express, which is single-threaded). I would assume even a starter Azure website could handle at least 4 AJAX calls every 5 seconds, but perhaps not. If decreasing the frequency minimized the issue, you may just need to more resources on your Azure site.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Yeah, thanks for the response. It's such a minimal load that I can't even imagine it is a problem like that. I feel that the `showUpdates()` function is failing one time, and it doesn't reach the `setTimeout()` function to recall the AJAX method. How could I build in a fail safe so that the `showUpdates()` function in my script will be recalled even if an error occurred the previous time (i.e. it failed to obtain and update the data)?

Comment: Well, you could just define an error function, and call it there as well. It's called, regardless, in the success function, whether everything else works or not.